# Adding columns in a query executed from a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, birt

I have a query in a stored procedure like below

```
select x,y from table
```

and the results will look like below

```
x y
1 a
1 b
2 a
2 b
3 a
3 b
```

i need to add a blank column or zeros when the value of x changes like below

```
x y
1 a
1 b
0 0
2 a
2 b
0 0
3 a
3 b
```

Can this be done by sql or since i'm using the data for birt reports can this be done with birt?

Comment: can you explain why you need to insert a row of zeros? it seems like an odd requirement to do something like this in sql.

Comment: I'm using the query data to make a report, and the report requirements need me to place a blank when the value of x changes

Comment: sounds like you're looking for the wrong solution to your problem. most reporting tools should be able to handle groups of data without having to manipulate the source data in this way. you need to use a group header row or something similar.

Comment: Thanks, somehow i didn't think of using group header as a blank row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need UNION ALL to add the extra rows, you also need to ORDER them, the DENSE_RANK is to get rid of the extra row.

here is how it could be done:

```
DECLARE @t table(x int, y char(1))
INSERT @t values
(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'a'),
(2,'b'),(3,'a'),(3,'b')

;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT
    2 rn, x,y, x sort from @t
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    distinct dense_rank() over (order by x desc) rn,  0, '0', x+.1 sort
  FROM @t
)
SELECT x,y
FROM CTE
WHERE rn > 1
ORDER BY sort, x
```

Result:

```
x   y
1   a
1   b
0   0
2   a
2   b
0   0
3   a
3   b
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working example:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [x] TINYINT
   ,[y] CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([x], [y])
VALUES (1, 'a')
      ,(1, 'b')
      ,(2, 'a')
      ,(2, 'b')
      ,(3, 'a')
      ,(3, 'b');

WITH DataSource AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM @DataSource
    UNION ALL
    -- the NULL will be always displayed on the first position
    SELECT DISTINCT [x]
                   ,NULL
    FROM @DataSource
)
SELECT IIF([Rank] = 1, 0, [x])
      ,IIF([Rank] = 1, 0, [x])
FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [x] ORDER BY [y]) AS [Rank]
          ,[x]
          ,[y]
    FROM DataSource
) DS
ORDER BY [x]
        ,[Rank]
```

[image]

Few important notes:

- the `NULL` values for each `x` will be with rank `1` always
- the final result set is sorted by `x` and `rank` both

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table (X varchar(1),Y varchar(1))
insert into @t(X,y) values (1,'A'),
(1,'B'),
(2,'A'),
(2,'B'),
(3,'A'),
(3,'B')


;with CTE As(
select X,Y,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY X,Y ORDER BY X)RN
from @t
CROSS APPLY
(
    values
        ('',NULL),
        ('',NULL)
) C(R, N)),
CTE2 AS(

Select CASE WHEN RN > 1 THEN 0 ELSE X END X ,
      CASE WHEN RN > 1 THEN CAST(0 AS VARCHAR) ELSE Y END ID 
      ,ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY X ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) R
       FROM CTE
)
select X,ID from cte2 where R <> 2
```